# How can I change the behaviour of lubuntu when wifi connection is lost?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lubuntu

Does anyone know how I can change what lubuntu (12.04) does when it loses the wifi signal? Right now it tries to reconnect - but after a few unseccessful tries it stops trying and asks for the admin password and/or the wifi-password. 
I want it to keep trying indefinitely without prompting any error messages etc.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Would you not rather find out and fix why it is disconnecting?

Comment: Thats not really my problem. It disconnects from time to time because of someone resetting the router. I simply just want it to keep trying to get a connection. Any ideas?

Comment: No answer here, no answer in ubuntu forums as well. What should I do now to get an answer? Any ideas? Someone? Please :)